# Styling GroupBox in QML 2

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I want to style GroupBox as below in QML 2 :

[image]

I am not finding How to do this in QML 2. In the following page, [Customizing Qt Quick controls](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-groupbox) there is no information on Styling Title.

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-63618 for the missing documentation.

Comment: It's strange that till now it is resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
GroupBox {
    id: control
    title: qsTr("GroupBox")
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    width: 300
    height: 150

    background: Rectangle {
        y: control.topPadding - control.padding
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height - control.topPadding + control.padding
        color: "transparent"
        border.color: "#21be2b"
        radius: 2
    }

    label: Rectangle {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.bottom: parent.top
        anchors.bottomMargin: -height/2
        color: "white"                  //set this to the background color
        width: parent.width * 0.7
        height: title.font.pixelSize
        Text {
            id: title
            text: qsTr("My Tilte")
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            font.pixelSize: 32
        }
    }
}
```

The more complicated solution if you want your label to be transparent is to use a Canvas to draw the background Rectangle:

**CustomBox.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.7

Item {
    id: box
    property string borderColor: "black"
    property int borderWidth: 1


    onWidthChanged: canvas.requestPaint()
    onHeightChanged: canvas.requestPaint()

    Canvas {
        id: canvas
        anchors.fill: parent
        antialiasing: true

        onPaint: {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

            ctx.strokeStyle = box.borderColor
            ctx.lineWidth = box.borderWidth
            ctx.beginPath()
            ctx.moveTo(width*0.15, 0)
            ctx.lineTo(0, 0)
            ctx.lineTo(0, height)
            ctx.lineTo(width, height)
            ctx.lineTo(width, 0)
            ctx.lineTo(width - width * 0.15, 0)
            ctx.stroke()
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
GroupBox {
    id: control
    title: qsTr("GroupBox")
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    width: 300
    height: 150

    background: CustomBox {
        y: control.topPadding - control.padding
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height - control.topPadding + control.padding
        borderColor: "black"
        borderWidth: 1
    }

    label: Rectangle {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.bottom: parent.top
        anchors.bottomMargin: -height/2
        color: "transparent"
        width: parent.width * 0.7
        height: title.font.pixelSize
        Text {
            id: title
            text: qsTr("Settings")
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            font.pixelSize: 32
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the main problem is the color of Label rectangle will be `transparent` and thus border of background rectangle is clearly visible. your solution works perfectly if not `transparent`.

Comment: I think Canvas will work for me.Thanks for the suggestions :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use label.x to set it in the middle

```
GroupBox { 
    title: "Potato"
    label.x: width/2 - label.contentWidth/2
    Label {
        text: "Wubba lubba dub dub."
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
GroupBox{
    id: id_keyListBox
    label: Label{
        text: "Choose an account to see details"
        color: "blue"
    }
```